# Multiple checkboxes in QDockWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

So I've been trying to make multiple checkboxes inside a QDockwidget but I seem to only be able to add one. This is what I have

```
def createDockWindows(self):
    cboxes = gui.QDockWidget("Cboxes", self)
    #cboxes.setWidget(gui.QCheckBox())
    cboxes.setAllowedAreas(core.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea)

    self.c0 = gui.QCheckBox("B0")
    self.c0.setChecked(False)
    self.c0.stateChanged.connect(lambda:self.btnstate(self.c0))
    cboxes.setWidget(self.c0)

    self.c1 = gui.QCheckBox("B1")
    self.c1.setChecked(False)
    self.c1.stateChanged.connect(lambda:self.btnstate(self.c1))
    cboxes.setWidget(self.c1)

    self.addDockWidget(core.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, cboxes)
```

The output only gives me the box for B1.

I've done the dock method because I have some matplotlib graphs over to the right, a modified version of [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html) example. If there is a better way to do this I'd be happy to change I'm just not finding much with google.

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qdockwidget.html#setWidget) to see how `setWidget()` works?

Comment: I do get B1 showing, just B0 is missing. I was working off of this example
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qcheckbox_widget.htm which does show me multiple boxes. Problem is QDockWidget doesn't have addWidget. So I'm wondering what to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a new widget, place a layout and add the checkboxes, that new widget you should add it to the QDockWidget.

```
def createDockWindows(self):
    cboxes = QtGui.QDockWidget("Cboxes", self)
    cboxes.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    w.setLayout(layout)

    self.c0 = QtGui.QCheckBox("B0")
    layout.addWidget(self.c0)

    self.c1 = QtGui.QCheckBox("B1")
    layout.addWidget(self.c1)

    cboxes.setWidget(w)
    self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, cboxes)
```

[image]

plus [add QSpacer]:

```
def createDockWindows(self):
    cboxes = QtGui.QDockWidget("Cboxes", self)
    cboxes.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    w.setLayout(layout)

    self.c0 = QtGui.QCheckBox("B0")
    layout.addWidget(self.c0)

    self.c1 = QtGui.QCheckBox("B1")
    layout.addWidget(self.c1)


    spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    layout.addItem(spacerItem)

    cboxes.setWidget(w)
    self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, cboxes)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing adding `w` here in one of my attempts. I do have the checkboxes spread out really far, is there a way to get it looking like yours? This is what mine looks like https://i.imgur.com/vvAkMws.png